# Redefine a Hotkey for Inverse Search in Kile under Miktex in Windows10?

Tags: editors, kile

I learned that there is a default hotkey, "shift + a-mouse-left-click", in Kile for an inverse search (taking one from a given point in the viewer to a near corresponding point in the editor. It is awesome. But, as I checked the shortcut adjustment options, I seemed to fail to find the option for a hotkey change for the inverse search. I am asking for a way to make that happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Kile DVI/PDF viewer is a subset of Okular and thus subject to any issues in that code.
There are open issues (bug reports) raised that the inverse command historically changed and whilst similar to some other viewers has now been fixed as Shift + Left Mouse Click, this is not useful to some users such as those with a Tablet.

Currently there is no way to change that behaviour via Okular settings.

Workarounds require either setting a [mouse button re-mapper](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) to duplicate Shift + Left Mouse Click or to use a platform app specific key re-mapper such as [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) for windows.